# ASP.NET MVC: Call one controller action from another, with ActionFilters applied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter, asp.net-mvc-controller

Take a look at the code below.

When `Get()` calls `Foobar()` and `Foobaz()`, the `ActionFilter`s that decorate `Foobar()` and `Foobaz()` are not invoked.

How can I call these other two controller actions from within `Get()` in a way that also causes the `SomeAction` and `AnotherAction` filters to execute?

```
public class Features : Controller
{
    [SomeAction]
    public bool Foobar(string id = null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    [AnotherAction]
    public bool Foobaz()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        return this.JsonResult(new Dictionary<string, bool>() 
        {
            { "foobar", this.Foobar() },
            { "foobaz", this.Foobaz() }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Controller actions aren't meant to be used as methods. In order for them to function properly they must be called within the request cycle. Perhaps your example is too simplistic, but it looks like you're trying to use these "actions" as just standard methods. While a controller can *technically* have a method that's never actually meant to be exposed as a route, it's not a good idea to do this sort of thing. Move the logic off into your model or some helper class.

Comment: Unfortunately, all this code is built wrong and I do not have the opportunity to correct and do things right. I somehow have to do what's shown, even if it means that `Get()` has to programmatically generate two HTTP requests that each spin up indenepdent controller instances. :(

Comment: If you're absolutely stuck doing it this way, I would suggest treating it like an API action and pull the data with `HttpClient` or similar.