# Calling Web API action from within an actionfilter to take advantage of outputcache for repeated authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-authorization

I wanted to take advantage of the OutputCache attribute for a authorization check to be made on an Action in a Controller. Based on a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089008/asp-net-mvc-call-one-controller-action-from-another-with-actionfilters-applied) and what I could tell the following design made sense, I was looking for feedback or corrections.
In other words:
1. a client calls an action on a controller which has my custom authorization filter attribute
2. The filter makes an HTTPClient call to another action on a web API controller (in the same site)
3. This action has an outputcache attribute to ensure I don't repeat an access check for the same parameters
Questions I had:
1. Is my use of OutputCache appropriate? I'm assuming a 5 minute cache lifetime.
2. In step#2 is a HttpClient call from my authorization filter the only way to make sure the pipeline for caching is built and used?

There are several related threads but I couldn't quite find one that tried to use this pattern for authorization.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I did build out the solution I'd designed.
Answers for the questions I had:
Q1: OutputCache attribute on the authorization check call seems to work fine, I had to vary it using the cookie parameter, I'm a little concerned about this given cookies come from the client, but I still have the forms authorization filter higher and that should reject completely un-authenticated requests from coming in, would be happy to change to a better solution.
Q2: If i didn't make an HTTP call from my filter, the cache pipeline was not being built, so this is necessary as far as i can tell.